# Sending documents with API and setting SignHere AnchorString vs Field Locators

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to Docusign so I'm testing the API.  I can send a document and ask for signatures in the places I need using the SignHere data structure and setting the AnchorString as defined in the [guide](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/tabs) in tab placement method 2.

I also read about Field Locators [here](https://developers.docusign.com/dsa-api/code-examples/local_04) and I thought they were for this purpose but they don't seem to work with the SignHere data structure so what is the purpose of them?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: are you planning to use Signature Appliance and its API or are you planning to use ESign Rest API? Field Locators are available with Signature Appliance API and it comes with extra cost and not all usecases need this Signature Appliance.

Answer (score 1):

The two things are you are referring to are related to two different products and two different APIs and cannot be mixed.
If you are going to use the DocuSign eSignature API, you can use the AhcorString, or you can specify X/Y coordinates for the SignHere tags.

The second link you had posted talking about the DSA, which is DocuSign Appliance and is a different technology (Digital Signature instead of Electronic Signature) and is not related to the SignHere tags